# How can I obfuscate (protect) my ionic (hybrid mobile app) project from reverse engneering/decompile?

Tags: ionic-framework, reverse-engineering, obfuscation, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-plugin-proguard

I want to Securing a **PhoneGap/Cordova Ionic Hybrid Mobile App** from reverse engneering/decompile apk/ipa to source code.

What are the tools available for **obfuscation**? please suggest

Comment: May i know what is the reason to down vote my question? I got my anwser after lots of research and it's a valid answer.

Comment: @JanP reply on your 1st Comment: I know better then you dear, when you can down vote the answer as my points shows everything. secondly if you know any thing about obfuscation put your answer instead of given your suggestion. respect this platform and don't misuse this platform.

Comment: Please have a look at the following thread about the use of the word "dear". Quite instructive... http://english.stackexchange.com/q/262405

Comment: hmm... why was this down voted ? - just an ego fight. lol

Comment: use cordova-plugin-proguard https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-setup-proguard-in-cordova-application/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got the answer of my query:

Javascript Obfuscator converts the JavaScript source code into obfuscated and completely unreadable form, preventing it from analysing and theft. It's a 100% safe JavaScript minifier and the best JavaScript compressor. It supports all the hybrid mobile apps.

[Use This Link](https://javascriptobfuscator.com/) and download the **GUI** to protect JavaScript source code into obfuscated code

Answer (score 1):

If you want secure your Ionic app from reverse-engineering and fully
secure your source code, I recommended two steps:

First use Enable ProGuard into your cordova/ionic project

1. To implement this, open /platforms/android/project.properties and
   uncomment this line by removing the `#` at left:
   #proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-
   project.txt
2. Copy [this proguard-custom.txt file](https://github.com/greybax/cordova-plugin-proguard/blob/master/proguard-custom.txt) to `android/assets/www/proguard-custom.txt` and remove the '#' at the beginning of these lines:

   ```
   #-keepclassmembers class android.webkit.WebView {
   # public *;
   # }
   ```
3. Add this snippet to `build.gradle`:

   ```
   buildTypes {
       debug {
           minifyEnabled true
           useProguard false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
       release {
           minifyEnabled true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   ```

Second, install [cordova-plugin-crypt-file](https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file) to obfuscate or encrypt your code:

1. Install: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crypt-file`
2. Update `plugins/cordova-plugin-crypt-file/plugin.xml`:

   ```xml
   //Using Reference of cordova-plugin-crypt
   <cryptfiles>
      <include>
        <file regex="\.(htm|html|js|css)$" />
     </include>
     <exclude>
       <file regex="exclude_file\.js$" />
     </exclude>
   </cryptfiles>
   ```

Final step:

```
ionic cordova build android --release
```

Now extract your apk or try [an APK decompiler](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk).

Comment: I followed all your steps. But when I run "ionic cordova build android --release", the proguard-custom.txt file inside platforms - android - assets - www -, disappears. But the build is successful though. Is that how it is supposed to be. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with paste proguard-custom.txt into android folder and i want to know after those step are you able to extreact your apk

Comment: Yeah, I did paste the file there. But once I build the application it's gone. I checked the apk file by unzipping it. The code is encrypted. So I think its okay.

Comment: how can we achieve the same for iOS build, please suggest.